# python array basic usage: step-function

Tags: python, arrays

I'm a beginner of python, rather confused about the array or list usage. Please help me with a rather basic usage as below, I just want to separate the data into two section, but I don't know how to :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import math
from pylab import *

i = np.arange(2,5,0.1)
t = 1+i
Light = 10
if  t > 3 :
  Light = 5

plt.figure('God Bless: Lightcure')
plt.plot(i,Light)
plt.show()
```

But this didn't work, traceback as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "1.py", line 11, in <module>
if  t> 3 :
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Thank you !

Comment: What do you expect `if t > 3` to do?

Comment: Do what the error message suggests

Comment: BTW you should consider to [change your question's title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: What do you mean by "separate the data into two sections"? Do you want to partition in two arrays or just know the index where the split should occurr?

Comment: Light = 10, but if t > 3, I want Light = 5

Comment: t is an array, in your code, while Light is a single value, a scalar. Do you want to make a sort of step-function that changes from 10 to 5 when t is greater than 3?

Comment: Yes, I want a step-function indeed!

Comment: @PaulChen For me it was obvious that you want step function but it would be better to explicitly state it in question.

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r yes, I want a step-function, how could this be revised?

Comment: @user3100115: FYI, your tag additions were rolled back by another user - is this OK? It doesn't look right to me, but I don't know these technologies. Perhaps this is just an array question, and so it doesn't need them?

Comment: @halfer well I added the tags because it's a `numpy`|`matplotlib` question so it's not OK. But the question is off-topic and now closed and I surely don't want to send it to the Reopen Vote queue by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# True is where condition is satisfied: numpy.ndarray([False, False, ..., True, True])
mask = t > 3

# Uninitialized array with same shape as t
Light = numpy.empty_like(t)

# Light elements set to 5 where corresponding mask elements are True
Light[mask] = 5

# Light elements set to 10 where corresponding mask elements are False
Light[~mask] = 10
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, I'm afraid I have problem how to ask a question. Still learn something from you, Thank you very much!